# How to substitude the JSON-JavaScript-Object, if it is not available?

Tags: javascript, json, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to substitude or replace the JSON-JavaScript-Object in case it is not available - what would be a neat way to achieve this?

**Situation:**

I have some code which uses `JSON.parse` and other functions to handle JSONs, but I have to migrate this code to be compatible to the Maple-Browser of a Samsung 2011-Series, which does not have a built-in JSON-Object.

jquery-1.6.2 lib is available; adding another lib is possible.

**Solution attempts:**

Found this nice blog http://www.greenhughes.com/content/experimental-couchdb-powered-samsung-internettv-app, which pretty much sums this problem up and even proviedes some solution. But this attempt seems to be 2 years old and I am looking for an improved solution.

**Goal:**

I would like to keep as much of my code as possible as it is and only handle somewhere the sitation, when a build-in JSON-Object is not available and then make it available in a way, that I do not have to change the calls to this Object.

---

Many thanks to any input or ideas to achieve this goal!

Comment: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js: "*json2.js: This file creates a `JSON` property in the global object, if there
isn't already one, setting its value to an object containing a `stringify` method and a `parse` method.*"

Comment: Also, these is a [JSON3](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3/) that [makes a few improvements](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3/#changes-from-json-2) over JSON2. More generally, what you want is called a "[polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill)" -- a library that "fills in" missing functionality in older browsers.

Comment: ok thanks! so i guess this project is still the best way to go ... i'll check it out